# Is there a way to save my current studio lighting in blender 2.8?

Tags: lighting, hdri

I currently have a lighting setup on my viewport. And I want to save it as my regular lighting setup. Is there a way to save it?

I hate the default HDRI and i want to have my basic default light.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just create a scene that has the elements you want.

Save the scene as the default scene.

File>Defaults>Save Startup File.

[image]

Next time you open blender, your lights will be there.